# Why I can't use value types in generic class with constraint where T : IEnumerable<object>

Tags: c#

I have generic class with constraint `where T : IEnumerable<object>`. I expected that I can use any type instead `object`. 
But when I try to create an instance of my generic class with `List<SomeValueType>` Visual studio gives me an error like `There is no implicit reference conversion from System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApp.Program.ValueType>' to System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'`. So my question is: why I can't use both value and reference types in this case even though they're both inherited from `object`?

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var example1 = new GenericClass<List<ReferenceType>>(); // it's ok

        // There is no implicit reference conversion 
        // from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<ConsoleApp.Program.ValueType>'
        // to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<object>'
        var example2 = new GenericClass<List<ValueType>>(); 
    }

    public class GenericClass<T> where T : IEnumerable<object>
    {

    }

    public class ReferenceType
    {

    }

    public struct ValueType
    {

    }
```

Comment: There's a flaw in the logic. The assumption here seems to be ValueType is an object so an IEnumerable<ValueType> is an IEnumerable<object>. But it's not, this show when we use a list example `var list = new List<ValueType>();` and then do something like `list.Add(new object());` you can't do this on a List of ValueType but that would be allowed if we did `var list = new List<object>()`. So we see that a IList<ValueType> is not the same as an IList<object>

Comment: @Knoop That doesn't really apply. `IEnumerable` doesn't let you *add* something. (If this was the case, OP's first example wouldn't work.)

Comment: @Rawling I was trying to give an intuitive example on why the basic logic is flawed

Comment: You can simplify it to `IEnumerable<Object> list = new List<ValueType>();` which is not allowed as opposed to `IEnumerable<Object> list = new List<ReferenceType>(); `

Comment: A Value Type holds the data within its own memory allocation and a Reference Type contains a pointer to another memory location that holds the real data. So an object is a reference type a value type is not, therefore you cannot use it. http://net-informations.com/faq/general/valuetype-referencetype.htm

Comment: @Rango in my opinion the add to a list is more intuitive. My assumption would be that most people would look at that and go 'hey, ofc you can't add an object to a list of a specific type!' The `IEnumerable<object> list = new List<ValueType>();` in my opinion is much closer to what visual studio is already stating: `IEnmuberable<ValueType> is not the same as IEnumerable<object>` which the op was unclear on. I just hope I didn't make the whole thing more complicated, since the whole goal was to give some insights.

Comment: @Knoop But `IEnumerable<T>` *does actually support covariance* on its generic argument, because it doesn't ever use the generic type as input in any operation, unlike a list, which is invariant because it uses its generic type argument for both input and output.  C# just doesn't support variance on value types, only reference types.  Saying an argument is easier to understand is pointless when *it's just wrong*.  Of course, I don't know why you think "C# doesn't support covariance on value types" is a complex explanation (it even has the benefit of being correct).

Comment: @Servy I did not know that, that's very interesting. Thanks for the explaination, makes sense to me now:-)